# How to calculate craps probabality of winning 20% starting with 100 playing $6 on place 6 with a fixed maximum number of rolls.

Tags: probability

In craps a place bet is traditionally not working unless there is a point.  You can however specify that you want your bet always working.
I want to calculate the probability of winning 20 dollars starting with a bankroll of 100 dollars and playing a $6 place 6 always working for a maximum of 500 rolls.  Betting stops if the goal is achieved before 500 rolls.
This is doable in a few hours on a bubble craps machine.
Simulation of a million sessions (python code included below) shows this goal is achieved 70 something percent of the time (73.226% with seed=0, 73.2705% with seed=1).

My initial thought was to just sum of the probabilities of the different ways to win.  Rolling 666, 7666, 67666, 66766, etc until I realized there were 323,224
such sequences in the million sessions that I simulated.  Note that 666 does not need to be rolled in 3 consecutive rolls.  Any other number may be rolled in between (as long as it is not a 7).  6236896 would be a 666 win.

What is the proper way to calculate this without simulation?

```
import random
random.seed(0)
sessions = 1_000_000
goal = 120
max_rolls = 500
bet_amount = 6
win_amount = 7  # every $6 pays $7
successes = 0
for _ in range(sessions):
    balance = 100
    rolls = 0
    balance -= bet_amount
    while balance >= 6 and rolls < max_rolls:
        rolls += 1
        roll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
        if roll == 6:
            balance += win_amount
            if bet_amount + balance >= goal:
                successes += 1
                break
        elif roll == 7:
            balance -= bet_amount
probability = successes / sessions
print(f'{successes=} {sessions=} goal% = {probability*100}%')
```

Comment: Do you quit early if you hit $+20$ or keep playing to $500$ rolls?  You should make it explicit that you do, not leave it to hide in the code.  Note that this is a losing bet, so if you in fact win $20$ over half the time the rest of the time you lose much more.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, betting stops if the goal is achieved before 500 rolls.  I added a note in the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your balance is executing a random walk: with each roll, it increases by $\$7$ with probability $5/36$, decreases by $\$6$ with probability $1/6$, and stays the same with probability $25/36$.  Starting with $\$100$, you want the probability that you will reach $\$120$ or more within the first $500$ rolls, without first getting to $\$5$ or less (since then you have too little to bet again).

You can calculate this using dynamic programming, working backwards from $t=500$ to $t=0$.  Let $P(b, t)$ be your probability of success given that your balance is $b$ after $t$ rolls.  At $t=500$, you're done rolling, so this is either zero (if $b<120$) or one (if $b\ge 120$).  For all earlier times, we say that $P(b,t)=0$ for $b \le 5$, $P(b,t)=1$ for $b\ge 120$, and otherwise
$$
P(b,t)=\frac{5}{36}P(b+7,t+1) + \frac{1}{6}P(b-6, t+1) + \frac{25}{36}P(b,t+1).
$$
You can then evaluate this with a spreadsheet, or a simple Python script like this:

```
def P(b, t, cache={}):
  if (b, t) in cache:
    return cache[(b, t)]
  if b >= 120: return 1
  if t >= 500 or b <= 5: return 0
  ret = (5/36) * P(b+7, t+1) + (1/6) * P(b-6, t+1) + (25/36) * P(b, t+1)
  cache[(b, t)] = ret
  return ret
```

Your answer, from `P(100, 0)`, comes out to be $0.734694196744$.  It's straightforward to get an exact (rational) result, too, with a denominator of $36^{500}$... the numerator is

10407753388217989703571455105733375660381012141631232413595990992450885584173913013668215998542882913799783667876632847134929308945114703437307910063128613251420450600317077349096150746242682153322696652693569482137425587066759076605654586827175321945841406817166255691083693282633828893625513225711675862220069436396004638506964504019538183603510372261308714494535112999111324516057347754928106465200530239047387066381088684305654931536309352089412462508793322797593557086878089922210382196654107580895710616517103882458338549735819239352385306217759613936545910494721862818581713968908749657837767076147951889834145144934995270240797598882722741804955725388943332239338129644304268848622852674750748888626270987409418891912175641716760223182688968003698807867403179384986813875.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is list the possible outcomes, the probabilities, and the amount of the win or loss.  We have
$$\begin {array} {r |r |r} \text{Roll}&\text{Probability}&\text{Gain}\\ \hline
6&\frac 5{36}&+7\\
7&\frac 6{36}&-6\\
\text{other}&\frac{25}{36}&0
\end {array}$$
Now calculate the number of $6$s you need to return $20$ for a given number of $7$s.  You can use the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) to compute the chance of any given distribution of rolls.  The fact that you quit early if you hit $+20$ makes it much harder.  You wind up with a lot of casework, which makes the simulation much easier.